# Dynamically create turtles

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

Is there any way to dynamically create turtles?

Whenever I try to create new random turtle in my "go" procedure, I get an error that I can't use `crt` in a turtle context. I need to be able to add some more turtles "on the fly" and creating a lot of invisible turtles looks like a dirty solution to me as well as it dramatically increases size of the model.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

While turtles can hatch turtles, you really should rewrite `go` so that it is not a turtle proc!  See

https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#ask

Comment: Note that the command for a turtle to "hatch" another turtle is `hatch`, https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#hatch